# SSRS Using IIF to determine what to SUM

Tags: reporting-services

I want to SUM the `Fields!DisbursementActualNetAmount.Value` where the `Fields!TransactionType.Value = "D"` but with the code I have created I keep getting `#error` in the textbox for the output. What am I doing incorrectly?

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!TransactionType.Value = "D", Fields!DisbursementActualNetAmount.Value, 0))
```

Comment: What data type is the `Fields!DisbursementActualNetAmount.Value` field?

Comment: It is type Money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the expression below to convert to decimal.

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!TransactionType.Value = "D", CDec(Fields!DisbursementActualNetAmount.Value), 0))
```

Comment: Same result. What does CDec do?

Comment: `CDec()` converts the value to a decimal. You might try converting to another data type and seeing if that works. I would guess it's something like that causing the error. The syntax looks fine.

Comment: Thank you, BJones! CInt(Fields!DisbursementActualNetAmount.Value) resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Actually I changed it to CDbl to account for the cents.

Comment: @sjreed28 - you may need to use CDEC(0). Or CDBL(0). It may be due to trying to add the Net Amount with the INT of zero.